# Android: Extract Values from a *.txt file

Tags: java, android

I have the following *.txt file

[Here for txt File](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2Ld8NlyYo3HUHBxdHozY2NhWWc/edit?usp=sharing)

How I can extract the Times in a Array or something else with its associated values in extra Array. Like

```
ArrayTime[..., 16:52, 17:07,....]
ArrayG[..., 533, 469,....]
ArrayGd[..., 186, 170,...]
```

How I can get the Values back from Array?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read each line of the file, ignore the top ones until the actual table begins.

split each line using space as a delimiter, that will give you an array with each of the 4 columns in it. Add entry in that single row array to respective ArrayLists that represent all of the values in each column.

Here is a bit of code to get you started:

```
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> g = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> gd = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> td = new ArrayList<String>();

String line = "";

//get a BufferedReader for your file.

while((line = br.readLine) != null){
    String row = line.split(" ");
    time.add(row[0]);
    g.add(row[1]);
    gd.add(row[2]);
    td.add(row[3]);
}
```

You'll have to work out how to skip the top lines that don't contain data, and you'll have to do conversions if you want to store your values as numeric instead of string. But this is the overall way that you can achieve what you are after.

**Note:** If there are leading spaces in the rows of the table you'll probably want to strip those out before calling the `split()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can make array as JSON object and make it in a string format and save it in your file. At the time of fetching, You can read the string and easily convert it to JSON object

```
String json;
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(File);
try {
    FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
    json = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
}
finally {
    stream.close();
}
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off storing your variables in a more simple manner, like

```
array=12:30,11:05,etc..
```

Then read the file line by line. Split the line by the "=" char, and then split the 2nd string by the commas to create an array.